# Webpack - resolve.moduleDirectories

Tags: webpack

I'm having issues with Webpack `resolve.moduleDirectories` config. The Documentation is really straight forward, but I cant get it working.

Given the following structure

```
app
├── config
│   └── routes.js
├── screens
│   └── App
│       └── screens
│           └── Admin
│               └── screens
│                   └── Reports
│                       └── index.js
├── shared
│   └── buttons
│      └── SignUp.js
```

I would like to use the component `shared/buttons/SignUp.js` on several parts of my app, so I suppose that I should use the following Webpack settings:

```
{
  modulesDirectories: ['shared', 'node_modules']
}
```

From `Reports/index.js`, I still cant include the button, even trying all the following includes:

```
import SubmitButton from 'buttons/SignUp.js';
import SubmitButton from 'buttons/SignUp';
import SubmitButton from 'shared/buttons/SignUp';
...
```

Is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong? I've placed an example here: https://github.com/henriquebf/resolve-webpack

Comment: In fact my problem is not related with webpack. I'm using Babel to load my JSX/ES6 files on the backend and I need to find a way to manage this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use imports like that, you can set up [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias).

Example:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        shared: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'shared')
    }
}
```

After this change `import SubmitButton from 'shared/buttons/SignUp';` should work. You can tweak aliases to your liking.